# Highstock second xAxis gridline does not stop at chart axis, but goes to bottom of div. Any suggestions?

Tags: highcharts

When I take the Highcharts meteogram example and simply replace highcharts.js with highstock.js

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/50wx7yp7/

the gridline for the second opposite xAxis passes down though the bottom xAxis, through the labels, to the bottom of the div.

Is there a way to prevent this? Not sure if this is a bug, or simply not possible. I need to use Highstock because I'm stacking multiple panes.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's causing the problem with such a complex example.  I would try adding a 2nd x axis to a normal example first - then you'll know if it's the library or the set up :)  Also, you don't need highstock in order to have multiple stacked y axes: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/KMA55/1/

Comment: @jlbriggs - Thanks very much for the jsfiddle example. I could have sworn I tried multiple y axes with highcharts before, and it didn't work. I'll test it again. Yes, my example is too complex - it was the quickest way right now (busy at work), but I have tried it with simpler versions with the same results.

Comment: @jlbriggs - Looking at your jsfiddle again, it seems to have the opposite problem. The vertical gridlines and plotbands don't reach the bottom x-axis of the bottom chart. Even the crosshairs on the tooltip don't reach it. Are you seeing that too?

Comment: Yes, see update: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/KMA55/3/  it's a matter of making sure you have the hieghts/tops of the axes, and the margin settings of the chart properly set.

Comment: @jlbriggs - Ah yes, thanks again. Sorry for asking such simple questions. I assumed the gridlines, etc would default to reach the bottom x-axis. They do in a single chart situation, but I guess the stacked panes are a bit trickier to format. Perhaps this is also my problem with the highstock version. I'll test it out later today. Many thanks.

Comment: I have reported it as possibly bug here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3367

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I didn't have time to make a simpler example last evening. It occurs with plot lines, plot bands, and opposite (top) xAxis grid lines, all in Highstock.